# Xamarain PlotView - change size of the View

Tags: android, xamarin

I would like to ask you how can i change size of the PlotView in code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">
    <OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android.PlotView
        android:id="@+id/plotView1"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

I wanna change android:layout_height="200dp" to other value.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This example sets it to 300dp. Place this code somewhere in your Activity.

```cs
var view = FindViewById(Resource.Id.plotView1);
var param = view.LayoutParameters;
param.Width = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, 300, Resources.DisplayMetrics);
view.LayoutParameters = param;
```

Comment: If this answers your question, mark the answer as accepted. Otherwise your question will remain in the unanswered section.